# Order by with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, one-to-many

I have a One-Many relation with two Entities :

```
Order:
int OrderId 
string OrderNumber
...

OrderItem:
int ItemId
int sequence
decimal Quantity
...
```

One `Order` Has multiple `OrderItems`, I want to write a Linq that return all orders with their items and items be sorted by sequence field.
How can i write a query such as following query?

```
Order myOrder = db.Orders.Include("OrderItems").Include("sequence").FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without projecting the results into a new type.

```
var myOrder= db.Orders.Include("OrderItems")
             .Where(x => x.OrderId == 3)  
             .Select(o => new {
                 order = o,
                 orderItems = o.OrderItems.OrderBy(i => i.sequence)
             }).FirstOrDefault();

// Usage
myOrder.order; // Order

myOrder.order.OrderItems; // OrderItems
myorder.orderItems;  // OrderItems alternative
```

Whilst it's not ideal projecting it into a new object, according to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx), there is a nice side-effect that now `order.OrderItems` on your anonymous object will be sorted correctly too.

Comment: It returns a collection of the anonymous type. Each item has `order` and `orderItems` properties.

Comment: what about if my method must return Order type not anonymous type?

Comment: I'm afraid what you're after is not possible. But the `order` property on the anonymous object is an actual `Order`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show usage and account for your question edits.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from a in Order 
             join b in OrderItems
                on a.Id equals b.OrderId
             order by b.sequence
             select new
             {     
                 a.Id,
                 b.sequence,
                 ...
             };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var temp = db.Orders.Include("OrderItems").Select(q => q.OrderItems.OrderBy(p => 
                     p.sequence)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks Niranjan, i edited my code could you plz check it again?

Answer (score -1):

```
var Orders = db.Orders.Include(a => a.OrderItems)
.OrderBy(a => a.OrderItems.sequence).ToList()
```

I recommend using lambdas to avoid the magic strings in your query.

Comment: but with this method i don't have access to sequence, because a.OrderItems is list of order items not a simple order item