# LINQ query orderBy a subquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

How do I order by date using LINQ query for an included table

```
    public async Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetTask(int id)
    {    
         var taskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
            .Where(u => u.Id == id)
            .Include(ts => ts.Notes.OrderBy(i => i.DateCreated))   //this is what needs to be in ascneding order of date
            .Include(ts => ts.Attachments)
            .Include(c => c.customer)
            .ToListAsync();      
            
        return taskSchedule;  
    }
```

Below code works, however, it does not sort out the notes in date ascending order

```
   public async Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetTask(int id)
    {    
         var taskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
            .Where(u => u.Id == id)
            .Include(ts => ts.Notes)
            .Include(ts => ts.Attachments)
            .Include(c => c.customer)
            .ToListAsync();
       
        return taskSchedule;  
    }
```

The error message i get is a 500 (Internal Server Error)

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Schedular.API.Models.Note]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[Schedular.API.Models.Note]'

This is the API data that comes back when I use the working code. The notes need to be in the order of the date it was created. Currently, it's the other way around.

```
[
{
    "id": 102,
    "title": "this should display",
    "start": null,
    "end": null,
    "isClosed": false,
    "highPriority": false,
    "hasTimeLimit": false,
    "customer": null,
    "customerId": null,
    "notes": [
        {
            "id": 70,
            "notesInfo": "add some notes first",
            "dateCreated": "2020-11-17T12:20:00",
            "user": null,
            "userId": 1,
            "taskScheduleId": 102
        },
        {
            "id": 72,
            "notesInfo": "add some notes second",
            "dateCreated": "2020-11-18T16:35:00",
            "user": null,
            "userId": 1,
            "taskScheduleId": 102
        },
        {
            "id": 73,
            "notesInfo": "add some notes third",
            "dateCreated": "2020-11-19T18:35:00",
            "user": null,
            "userId": 1,
            "taskScheduleId": 102
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [],
    "userCurrentAssignedId": 1,
    "userCurrentAssigned": null,
    "userLastEditId": 1,
    "userLastEdit": null,
    "userLastEditDate": "2020-11-19T15:37:00",
    "taskCreatedDate": "2020-11-19T15:37:00"
}
```

]

Comment: Include the error message to the question. Most importantly your question is not clear. Are you wanting Notes child collection should be ordered by  DateCreated?

Comment: obviously `Include` expects to get expression which points to property not `IQueryable` ...

Comment: Which EF version do you use?

Comment: EF version 3.1.4.
I've included the error message and the API data that I get back when I remove orderby.

Comment: You probably have to do it in a `Select` statement since you can't use it in an `Include`

Comment: @GolfBravo, this feature is available only in EF Core 5  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by with Linq + Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477389/order-by-with-linq-include)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv will it work without `Skip`/`Take`?

Comment: @GuruStron, sure. Skip/Take just adds complexity.

Comment: I did look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477389/order-by-with-linq-include before I asked the question but the format they used is different to mine and I couldn't match it up.

Comment: Thats the old include. But the key part is still in the select part. Yep alot have change in C# in the last 7 years we went from string include to type safe include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid use `OrderBy` inside `Include`,change like below:

```
var taskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
        .Where(u => u.Id == id)
        .Include(ts => ts.Notes)
        .Include(ts => ts.Attachments)
        .Include(c => c.customer)
        .ToListAsync();

taskSchedule.ForEach(t => t.Notes = t.Notes.OrderBy(n => n.DateCreated).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

To sum-up this question and comments.

This query originally supported only by [EF Core 5 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include). `Include` is not a subquery it's a directive for EF Core to load related entities and evolution of this functionality is introduced in EF Core 5.

Anyway, usually it is not needed to do such queries because they are related to DTO mapping. So just do such mapping by hands and this query should work for EF Core 3.x also.

```cs
 var taskSchedule = 
    from ts in await _context.TaskSchedules
    where ts.Id == id
    select new TaskScheduleDTO
    {
        Notes = ts.Notes.OrderBy(n => n.DateCreated).ToList(),
        Attachments = ts.Attachments.ToList(),
        Cutomser = ts.Customer
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to take your initial advice and upgrade to .net 5. I read the document you sent and it makes sense to go down that route.